# How can I get a document URL suitable for use by the .NET Sharepoint API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I'm editing an Excel document hosted on Sharepoint that has a url like this:

> https://{mysite}.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/{name}/ETxQX66YJ...XOmOv1SYLDA?rtime=mqEhNZwV10g

I want to be able to read this programmatically using code like this:

```
Using clientContext = New ClientContext("https://{mysite}.sharepoint.com/")
  clientContext.Credentials = ...

  Dim file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/:x:/g/personal/{name}/ETxQX66YJ...XOmOv1SYLDA?rtime=mqEhNZwV10g")

  Dim data = file.OpenBinaryStream()
  clientContext.Load(file)
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
  ...
End Using
```

The connection works fine, but the `ExecuteQuery` fails with:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name.'

I assume this is because of the colons in the relative url, and that there is another url endpoint that I'm supposed to use to access this file, but I can't figure out what it is.

What is that correct format or else how can I determine what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of SP you are using. Assuming SP Online, then have you tried getting the link from the *copy or get link* options for the file? From memory, I believe you need to try the *restricted* option.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are using seems a sharing link in SharePoint Online, for GetFileByServerRelativeUrl function, should pass the file server raltive url.

For example the complete file url is:

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/test33.jpg

Then the file relative url is:

/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/test33.jpg

```
  Dim file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/test33.jpg")
```

Comment: That sounds right but how do I *find* that server relative url?

Comment: You can refer the demo above, file relative url just remove your tenant url and starts with site relative url /sites/dev/Libraryname/filename

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `GetFileByUrl` (new) instead of `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl`, to get a file from the shareable link like yours. It should resolve such links.

```cs
clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl("https://{mysite}.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/{name}/ETxQX66YJ...XOmOv1SYLDA?rtime=mqEhNZwV10g")
```